# GTK ListView With Multiple Objects?

Tags: gtk, pygtk

How can I create a listview that includes other objects such as image, link, etc. in GTK? What I mean is, just like these Android ListViews:

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/images/listview_contextual10.png

What I want is:

http://pic002.cnblogs.com/images/2012/372551/2012021011374176.jpg

How can I do that in GTK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy way is to create a custom widget that lays out the text and images how you want it, and then put that into a `GtkVBox` and put that `GtkVBox` into `GtkScrolledWindow`

This isn't really any easy way to do it with `GtkTreeView`

Comment: By the way, how can I make these VBox'es clickable?

Comment: You could put them in GtkEventBox